# Saving to existing Parse.com object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I am receiving the following errors [1]"Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'. [2]Cannot invoke 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool, NSError?) -> Void)'. I am attempting to save an integer to an existing parse.com column.

```
func heatUp(){
    let findDataParse = PFQuery(className:"flyerDataFetch")
    findDataParse.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectID)
    findDataParse.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (ObjectHolder: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
                //[1] First error
                 if let ObjectHolder = ObjectHolder {
                    ObjectHolder["attention"] = self.count
                }
                //[2] Second error
                ObjectHolder.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (success){
                        println("successful save")
                    }
                  }
                 }
                }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put PFObject instead of anyobject (convert it) and for error erase it or dont put it as optional

Comment: (ObjectHolder: PFObject, error: NSError?) -> Void in    What exactly do you mean by convert?

Comment: you are querying PFObject named flyerDataFetch ... and you want to get result of objects (in this particular example only one object because id is unique)  ... u make background thread to query through objects and u get query with results of anyObjects (as we said - u only get one object but that object is stored in array). To read this object u must convert it in PFObject so that parse understands that it is an object from db and that it can read from it. So u unwrap that anyobject as pfobject (if let .. as? PFObject) and when u do that u can read its properties with object["property"] method

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
(ObjectHolder: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

To

```
(ObjectHolder: [String]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what this code is supposed to do, but...

Error 1: ObjectHolder is an array of AnyObject types. You're trying to get the "attention" index of ObjectHolder which isn't possible. Remember, only numeric values go into the [] of an array for indexing. For example, if you want to get the first value in the array:

```
value = array[0]
```

You probably want to get the first PFObject in ObjectHolder using ObjectHolder[0] and THEN do the editing of that column.

```
object = ObjectHolder[0]
object["attention"] = self.count
```

Error 2: Again, you're trying to do an array of operations on a list of objects. Using the object you just created above, do:

```
object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {...
```